# why can't I run this perl code?

Tags: perl

While following this tutorial

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3152/Perl-Object-Oriented-Programming

I am failing to see where module Address.pm is.. did I miss something or article has an error or do I have a misunderstanding when one of the module says ' use Address ';

```
mac1:moduleTEST1 user1$ ./Employee.pl
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Address" (perhaps you forgot to load "Address"?) at ./Employee.pl line 16.
mac1:moduleTEST1 user1$
```

Comment: Don't follow 15 year old tutorials that were bad the moment they were written. See also [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049517.do). As for `Address.pm`, it is not included on the page.

Comment: As @SinanÜnür points out, this is an old and not-so-great tutorial.  Of course you have no way to tell that it sucks, since it has 5 stars on that site.  Try starting here: https://www.perl.org/learn.html  You also might find the official OO tutorial in the perl manual pages useful: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a misunderstanding on your part.  There indded need be `use Address;` in the code, but that module isn't shown. I also strongly suggest to use other resources, btw.

Comment: so guys, thank you and I will follow other sites.. I thought this decent since it had couple modules put together and try to use it so that I can understand better.  I will check out suggested resource.

Comment: Use the ample documentation that is installed with Perl on *your* computer. `perldoc perltoc`, `perltoc perlootut`, and `perldoc perlobj`.

Comment: BTW, I just have to add a comment. It's best to learn from complete example and some of the resource gives you little snippets but not necessarily complete picture end to end and that's why I was looking at other stuff. It is very possible that I didn't look at already mentioned tutorial and I intend to study them throughly tonight.

Comment: Sure, complete examples are good. You'll find plenty of them which are _much_ better than that "tutorial."  (I am not blaming _you_ :)  I'd suggest some of the very good books on Perl that are out there.  Also, the official documentation linked by @Sinan is excellent. And the SO itself in fact has a lot of posts with complete examples.

Comment: I am sorry but I must respectively disagreed. I do not find official perl doc which was linked having complete end to end examples. I would like tutorial to have complete yet concise modules to show most object oriented ideas  and also perl script itself to call them and use it. I feel like that helps more than snippets that I see on these tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial is outdated and rather useless. Specifically, it is much worse than the documentation which comes with Perl. Use `perldoc perltoc` to get a table of contents, and read everything at least once.

See [`perldoc perlootut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) and [`perldoc perlobj`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

```
package Address;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $args = shift;
    my %self = map +($_ => $args->{$_}), qw( street city state zip );
    bless \%self => $class;
}

sub street {
    my $self = shift;
    if ( @_ ) {
        $self->{street} = $_[0];
        return;
    }
    return $self->{street};
}

# ditto for the rest of the accessors # there are
# ways to cut down the boilerplate once you learn
# the basics
#
# ...


__PACKAGE__
__END__
```

You use this module like this:

```
 my $address = Address->new({
    street => '123 E. Any St',
    city => 'Any Town',
    state => 'AY',
    zip => '98765',
 });
```

Of course, there a lot of things missing from this little demo. For example, the accessor, as written, allows you to change the state of the object. Immutable objects are easier to reason about, so you might want to disallow that by changing it to:

```
 sub street { $_[0]->{street} }
```

It also allows you to assign any value you want to fields like `state` and `zip`. So, you may want to validate those values in the constructor, ensure that only values for the fields of the class are passed, all the values passed are defined etc.

At the end of that process, you may decide it doesn't make sense to keep writing boilerplate and use [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) or [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) to avail yourself to a richer set of features.

Even then, it helps to know what's happening under the hood.

Comment: It is a stunningly bad tutorial, leaving out the missing `u`s on some of the `use` statements, it has sample code that uses a module that it doesn't provide source for.  And of course, there's the indirect object notation.

Comment: What's with the needlessly noisy `->new({ ... })` instead of `->new( ... )`?!

Comment: seriously, what is     my %self = map +($_ => $args->{$_}), qw( street city state zip );
  ???